# Related to Digital signiature

Tags: apex, security, encryption, crypto, decrypt

## Something related to Digital signature

if we have a doc in sales-force and needs to be **digitally signed**,  which involves **digital certificates**.. and how we can use **crypto** class of apex in this. also how to **verify that Digital signature** in other peer for **authenticity and integrity of the message.**

If its come to **digital signature**, We use **private and public key certificate** for encrypt and decrypt the message. then **how i can generate a public and private certificate in salesforce certificate key management**.

Needed very solution very badly for this, Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: i have a code for signing the document and the sign will store in the attachment of the object using visual force page and apex class @NITHESH K

Comment: Can share me a code of that for understanding .  My this  question also related my one more question present in StackExchange https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190290/how-to-obtain-the-original-text-from-encrypted-text-in-signwithcertificate-met/190307#190307

Comment: but i have not use crypto, just using vf page and apex class, it will capture the sign and store in the attachment of the particular object

Comment: how did you obtain signature without using crypto class? Used any external api ?

Comment: In my above question,  First i have to put digital signature to file , Then i have to verify that file in other peer.

Comment: i have created the custom button like signature , if you click that button, the box will open , after that i will sign in that box , down save button will be there,if you click save then it will store in the attachment of the object

Comment: i think you are expecting some otherthing right?

Comment: yes some what like that. but i wanted to sign the document using .crt file with is present in salesforce certificate key management .

Comment: @ NITHESH K, i dont know about using .crt file with is present

Comment: Can u share what you have done, So that i can get any idea about that

Comment: Yup sure. I will .

Answer (score 2):

> Apex class for capturing the sign

```
public class signAccountExtension {
    Id accountId;

    public string fileData { get; set; }

    public signAccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        accountId = controller.getId();
    }
    public void saveImage() {
        insert new Attachment(
            ContentType='image/jpeg',
            Body=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileData),
            Name='Signature',
            ParentId = accountId
        );
    }
}
```

> Visual Force Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="signAccountExtension">
    <style>
        #signature {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!saveImage}" name="saveImageToServer" reRender="">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!fileData}" name="data" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <canvas id="signature" width="400" height="100" />
        <button id="save">
            Save
        </button>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    !function() {
        var canvas, lastX, lastY;
        function start(event) {
            lastX = event.offsetX;
            lastY = event.offsetY;
            document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
            document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", end);
        }
        function draw(event) {
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            if(event.target === canvas) {
                context.fillStyle = "black";
                context.strokeStyle = "black";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
                context.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 3);
                context.stroke();
                lastX = event.offsetX;
                lastY = event.offsetY;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        function end(event) {
            document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", draw);
            document.body.removeEventListener("mouseup", end);
            canvas.removeEventListener("mouseenter", mouseenter);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        function save(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            saveImageToServer(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").split(/;base64,/)[1]);
        }
        function init() {
            var context;
            canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start);


            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.fillStyle = "white";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save);
        }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
    }()
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes i read about this solution before .There storing in attachment , Signature draw in canvas window ..

Comment: but i dont know about your using crtfile requirement,i have done like this manner only

Comment: this i kind alternative for storing the signature.   if you look https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm  , click on funcion "signWithCertificate(algorithmName, input, certDevName)"  this method will generate  a signature based on org certificate and input file .

Comment: No problem, I appreciated for your help.

Comment: @NITHESHK https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190290/how-to-obtain-the-original-text-from-encrypted-text-in-signwithcertificate-met/190307#190307 , i saw you question here, sfdcfox answered in good and correct manner, so it may not be possible i think so

Comment: @NITHESHK all the best

Comment: Yes, i am looking alternative solution for my question. it was my project requirement so.

Comment: @NITHESHK,I am facing one small doubt?,In workflow rule, time trigger option is there, if you click add time trigger, it will opens ,In that Rule trigger Date option is there?,Rule trigger Date denotes which date?please explain

Comment: When ever you create a time Trigger, its always ask for {number Days}, After/Before {field value} .  In Fields drop down list, you get see all date field which workflow is related to Sobject.   That means your trigger always execute before/after the value of the field Value.

Comment: your comment is not at all related here .

Comment: you need not worry about those month capacity. Contract End Date is 12/12/2021  before 90 days, means before exactly 90 there to reach the Contract End Date is 12/12/2021

Comment: Three Months means we cannot calculate exact date ah?,I s there any solution ?wait i will post new question

Comment: Please observe there no month, Only days or hours  option is there. its doesn't effect . if it is in month surely i could agree your question.

Comment: @SFDC it working fine in desktop but on mobile browser it's not allowing draw signature  there is no error popup, just not allowing to draw