# How to obtain the original text from encrypted text in signWithCertificate() method

Tags: apex, controller, security, encryption, crypto

> I have problem with working with digital signature.

In controller **encryptWithManagedIV()** function is encrypted and decrypted properly.  But i don't  know how to work with **signWithCertificate**, how to get the original text back from encrypted data. Any one can help me.

"SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100" my org certificate name , we can get in Certificate and Key Management inside setup .

**Visual force page :**

```
<apex:page controller="DigiSig" >
     <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="section" title="My Content" mode="edit">            
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section"  columns="5">
                <apex:outputText > originalText : {! originalText } </apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText > encryptedText : {! encryptedText } </apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText > decryptedText : {! decryptedText } </apex:outputText>                        
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!signWithCertificate}" reRender="section" value="signWithCertificate"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!encryptWithManagedIV}" reRender="section" value="encryptWithManagedIV"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>       
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

**Controller : DigSig**

```
public class DigiSig {
    public String originalText{get;set;}
    public String encryptedText{get;set;}
    Public String decryptedText{get;set;}

    public DigiSig(){}  

    public void signWithCertificate(){
        decryptedText='';
        originalText= 'Test data to encrypted';
        Blob data = Blob.valueOf(originalText);
        Blob ans= System.Crypto.signWithCertificate('RSA-SHA256', data, 'SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100'); // "SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100" my org certificate name , we can get in Certificate and Key Management inside setup 
        encryptedText= EncodingUtil.base64Encode(ans);

        ans= System.Crypto.signWithCertificate('RSA-SHA256', ans, 'SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100');

        // how to get decrypted text here from "ans"
        // decryptedText=  ???????

        System.debug('************  ans' + ans);
        System.debug('************  working');  
    }

    public void encryptWithManagedIV(){
        originalText= 'Test data to encrypted';
        Blob data = Blob.valueOf(originalText);
        Blob  key = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
        Blob ans =Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, data);
        encryptedText= EncodingUtil.base64Encode(ans);

        decryptedText= Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, ans).toString();

        System.debug('************  ans' + ans);
        System.debug('************  working'); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recover the original data from a *signature*. A signature is proof that a specific input was signed with a specific certificate. You use a signature to verify the authenticity of data you have received. A mismatch of the signature means that the data has been altered. If you want to encrypt and decrypt data, use the encrypt/encryptWithManagedIv and decrypt/decryptWithMangedIv methods.

Comment: In order to verify the signature in other peer , user must have this certificate right.  That means each peer i have to share my certificate with them ?

Comment: @NITHESHK If you're doing peer authentication, each will have their own private certificate and public certificate. The private certificate is used to create the signature, and the public certificate is used to verify the signature. So, you would give your public certificate to the peer, and they could verify the signature.

Comment: @sfdfox  i have few more doubt on Certificate generated by the org ,  this is "SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100" org generated certificated i have to use in signWithCertificate(), And i don't have two certificate for private and public . How can achieve this.

Comment: "SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100" certificate i have used to encrypt the data, same "SelfSignedCert_01Aug2017_114100" certificate only i have to share with peer ?

Comment: if your saying , "The private certificate is used to create the signature, and the public certificate is used to verify the signature." then how can i generate private certificate  & public certificate and how to used it in above code . Please any help will appreciated.

Comment: @sfdfox Any help on this , needed solution for this greatly .

Comment: @NITHESHK Your question is one thing, and now you're saying something else. What is your underlying objective?

Comment: Yea i agree. Answer for above questions i have received from u. But still confused if i signed any documents with signwithcertificate() method, how to verify in other peer.  Saleforce certificate key management provide only .crt file. Using that file i have generated signature through signwithcertificate (),. I don't know what is the next step i have to do with other peer to verify this document authenticity and integrity.

Comment: @NITHESHK Far as I can tell, you can't verify a signature in Apex Code, but most other languages have support for this. See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20945)

Comment: @sfdfox Thank you.  can you provide any solution for my this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190098/related-to-digital-signiature   needed very badly for my project.